# Replacing Parts of a Data Frame in r

Tags: r

list:

```
number name age status 
1      ben  34  m
2      max  12  s
3           27  s
4           42  d
```

I have this list and I have tried to replace the empty parts in "name" coulm.

this is my code (all my tries):

```
list$name[3] <- "eric"
list[3,2] <- "eric"
list[3,2] <- 0
list[is.na(list)] <- 0
```

this is the error:

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, 3, value = c(2L, 3L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = 0) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

do you know what's the problem?

Comment: try `list$name[[3]] <- "eric"`

Comment: You should read about factor variables. A good source for this is e.g.  "Advanced R " by Hadley Wickham: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html. An easy way to solve your problem is to transform your factor variable to a character variable using `as.character()`.

Comment: try as.character() and [[3]] and I got the same warning.

Comment: `list$name <- as.character(list$name)`

Comment: tnx alex, it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`name` is a factor column and you're trying to add more "levels" which have not been defined.

You can either coerce the column to a `character` column and edit as you tried or add the levels to the factor column.

```
list$name <- as.character(list$name)
list$name[3] <- "eric"
```

or

```
list$name <- factor(list$name, levels=c(levels(list$name), "eric"))
list$name[3] <- "eric"
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23316815/add-extra-level-to-factors-in-data-frame-in-r) for more details.