# How to specify a column as.factor with read.excel() in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, readxl

I am trying to read a dataframe from an Excel file using the `read_excel()` function from the `Tidyverse` (`ReadXl`) package in R. I would like to read a column `as.factor`, however, the `col_types` argument in the `read_excel()` function does not seem to support `as_factor`.

I now use the following workaround:

Sample code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

df <– read_excel("name_of_excel_file.xlsx")

df <- df %>% 
     mutate(column = as.factor(column))
```

Is there an easier (and more direct) way to do this?

Comment: AFAIK that's the best there is. Any reason why that doesn't work well for you?

Comment: Not really. `col_types` won't take "factor" as a data type. Though, of course, you could `mutate_at` if you want, which is slightly less redundant.

Comment: @camille It does work well, however, it is an operation that I need to perform quite regularly, so I was wondering if it might be optimized somehow.

Comment: Although you don't specify if you must use the `readxl` package, if you do, you need the added step because direct coercing to factors is not allowed (https://readxl.tidyverse.org/articles/cell-and-column-types.html). Character to factor should be a conscious conversion, remember that adding categories after the fact is hard (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23316815/add-extra-level-to-factors-in-dataframe).

Answer (score 2):

Reference: http://bradleyboehmke.github.io/tutorials/importing_data

Try:

```
library(xlsx)

df <- read.xlsx("name_of_excel_file.xlsx", sheetName = "Sheet1",
                             stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```